# JDBC driver not found on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, java, mysql

I recently updated the Ubuntu OS and now I cannot get the Java programs to connect to the MySQL database. The following error occurs:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/PTAX?useSSL=false
```

I searched the web and the only thing I found was to install `libmysql-java`. However, when I try to install it, the message below occurs.

```
Unable to locate package libmysql-java
```

Answer (score 6):

Had found this 'answer', then did some more digging about and found a [post on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/pop_os/comments/ebdj0t/unable_to_install_libmysqljava_on_pop_os_1910/) saying this package was merged in to `libmariabd-java`:

> I found the solution. The `libmysql-java` has been (I think merged) with `libmariadb-java`. So, I just installed it using
>
> ```
> sudo apt install libmariadb-java
> ```
>
> After that just repeated the same steps as I would do with 18.04 and it worked! No problems whatsoever.

Comment: in 22.04 LTS this seemed to not solve my problem

Answer (score 6):

I think the package is now called mysql-connector-java and can be downloaded from mysql.com/products/connector.
This article might also be helpful:
https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/MySQLJava/article.html
Edited to add this suggestion:
If you add the mysql repos to ubuntu or debian (howto on mysql website) then the command:
sudo apt install mysql-connector-java pulls the file from those repos.