# Ubuntu 20.04 - MySQL JDBC driver

Tags: 20.04, java, mysql, mariadb

Is there a way to install MySQL JDBC driver from Ubuntu 20.04 repository?

It looks from other questions ([askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1285421/jdbc-driver-not-found-on-ubuntu-20-04), [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128966/where-is-the-mysql-jdbc-jar-file-in-ubuntu)) that it was contained in **libmysql-java** (which is no longer there), and then moved to **libmariadb-java** (weird because as far as I know, it's different database - but I found sort of confirmation on [debian package description](https://packages.debian.org/sid/libmariadb-java)).

So I installed **libmariadb-java**, but for me it doesn't look like it's there. Here's the result of running *dpkg-query -L libmariadb-java*:

```
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libmariadb-java
/usr/share/doc/libmariadb-java/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libmariadb-java/copyright
/usr/share/java
/usr/share/java/mariadb-java-client.jar
/usr/share/maven-repo
/usr/share/maven-repo/org
/usr/share/maven-repo/org/mariadb
/usr/share/maven-repo/org/mariadb/jdbc
/usr/share/maven-repo/org/mariadb/jdbc/mariadb-java-client
/usr/share/maven-repo/org/mariadb/jdbc/mariadb-java-client/2.5.3
/usr/share/maven-repo/org/mariadb/jdbc/mariadb-java-client/2.5.3/mariadb-java-client-2.5.3.pom
/usr/share/maven-repo/org/mariadb/jdbc/mariadb-java-client/debian
/usr/share/maven-repo/org/mariadb/jdbc/mariadb-java-client/debian/mariadb-java-client-debian.pom
/usr/share/java/mariadb-java-client-2.5.3.jar
/usr/share/maven-repo/org/mariadb/jdbc/mariadb-java-client/2.5.3/mariadb-java-client-2.5.3.jar
/usr/share/maven-repo/org/mariadb/jdbc/mariadb-java-client/debian/mariadb-java-client-debian.jar
```

It seems it helped others, so what am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

While the question asks for an install through the *repository*, let me give a solution involving a DEB file, as this might be helpful for others:

Download "JDBC Driver for MySQL (Connector/J)" from https://www.mysql.com/products/connector/

You can select the desired Ubuntu version there.

Then install this .DEB file as follows:

```
sudo dpkg -i mysql-connector-java_8.0.25-1ubuntu20.04_all.deb
```

Comment: you cannot install it like that, you have to use `dpkg -i FINELNAME.deb`

Comment: well, I actually could, e.g. in Ubuntu 18.04 or 22.04 - but I changed my answer now to the more common command you suggested, to avoid trouble for others and to follow the official Ubuntu help