# JDBC Driver Error after Ubuntu upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04

Tags: upgrade, mysql

I recently upgraded the Ubuntu version from 18.04 to 20.04 (using `do-release-upgrade`) on a machine running MySQL server.

Now I get on the client machine the following error message in programs using the Java database connector:

```
JDBC Driver Error: Communications link failure
```

I am pretty sure that the MySQL server is up and running well, for example, I can access it from the same machine as follows:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message `JDBC Driver Error: Communications link failure` is not very specific - this could be e.g. due to MySQL server not running at all, or due to a connection not being usable for the client e.g. due to a version mismatch.

In my case, it was a version mismatch between MySQL server (whose version was updated to 8.0.30 following the Ubuntu distribution upgrade to 20.04), and the MySQL connector on the client side.

To fix the problem, unlike the error message states, no changes on the server were needed.

On the client machine, I installed the MySQL connector matching the MySQL server version, according to [the guide in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1339372/1263712).